# Pig Latin game resolved with a regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, pig-latin

I recreated the [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) game on Java. The program takes an arbitrary number of command line arguments as words, and prints to the standard output these words translated with following rules:

- For words that **begins with a consonants**, all letters until first vowel are moved to the end, and it is added the sequence "ay";
- For words that **begins with a vowel**, it is simply added the sequence "way".

About the implementation, I've used a *regular expression* to split the word. I think that it is an elegant solution, maybe less efficient against a specific implementation of the rules.

The code is composed only with a class, `PigLatin`. You can compile it with `javac PigLatin.java` and run with `java PigLatin <word> ...`. Here there is **PigLatin.java**:

```
/**
 * This small program implements the game Pig Latin. You can specify one or more
 * words as a command line argument, and the program will print the modified
 * version on the standard output.
 *
 * The rules of the game are:
 *      - For words that begin with a consonant, all letters before the first
 *        vowel are placed at the end of the word, then the sequence "ay" is
 *        appended.
 *      - For words that begin with a vowel, it is appended the sequence "way".
 *
 * Note that command line arguments are limited.
 *
 * Note that you should only use uppercase or lowercase letters.
 */
public class PigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(convertWord(args[i]));

            if (i < args.length - 1)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /*
     * This method convert a word using Pig Latin rules.
     *
     * @param word the word to convert
     *
     * @return the converted word
     */
    private static String convertWord(String word) {
        /* If the word begins with a consonant (or more), this regex splits the
         * word into two groups: the first are the consonants before the first
         * vowel, the second is the rest of the string.
         * If the word begins with a vowel, only a single group is returned.
         */
        String[] tokens = word.split("^([^aeiouAEIOU]*)(\\w*)");

        if (tokens.length == 2)
            return String.join(tokens[1], tokens[0], "ay");
        else
            return word + "way";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I would write this with a different approach. It is up to you, which is better.

```
public static String pigLatin(String word) {
    Pattern firstVowelPattern = Pattern.compile("^([aeiouAEIOU])");
    Matcher matcher = firstVowelPattern.matcher(word);
    if (matcher.find()) return word + "way";
    return word.replaceAll("^([^aeiouAEIOU]*)(.+)", "$2$1ay");
}
```

I do not use any arrays and splitting a string, but I solve it with more regex expressions.  The key element of this solution is how replaceAll works. In the first parameter, I pass two regex expression and in second parameter I switch results of them using $2$1.

As you can see I did not use `if-else` statement, only `if`. In your solution `else` also is redundant.